# Permutate two lists but keep index

Tags: python, list, permutation

I want to permutate over all possible combinations of two lists, but I want that each element remains at its index. Here is an example of what I want to achieve.

`[1, 2, 3] and [a, b, c] should give: [1, 2, 3], [a, 2, 3], [1, b, 3], [1, 2, c], [a, b, 3], etc`

Is there a neat way to achieve this result?

A normal permutation switches the place of in elements of the list, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: "etc." implies that the pattern is clear, but in this case it isn't. For one thing, it doesn't seem like you are talking about permutations at all but more like combinations of the index set. How many lists are implicit in your "etc.? 3? More?

Comment: You actually can use all bit sequences of the length of the lists and for a given sequence for each bit 0 take item from first list, for each bit 1 take item from second. The bit sequences can be created from int numbers counting upwards from 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import product

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

out = list(product(*zip(list1, list2)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 'c'),
 (1, 'b', 3),
 (1, 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 2, 3),
 ('a', 2, 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 3),
 ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

If the order is important:

```
out = [list(x[::-1]) for x in product(*zip(list1[::-1], list2[::-1]))]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 ['a', 2, 3],
 [1, 'b', 3],
 ['a', 'b', 3],
 [1, 2, 'c'],
 ['a', 2, 'c'],
 [1, 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Oh, that one wins the prize. I should have though of `product` rather than overthinking my one-liner.

Comment: @chrslg Thanks. I like `itertools`, it makes it easy to generalize to an arbitrary number of lists: `list(product(*zip(list1, list2, list3)))` ;)

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner

```py
[[l2[k] if (2**k&i) else l1[k] for k in range(len(l1))] for i in range(2**len(l1))]
```

Principle is to use binary number i (I mean interpreted as binary; number have no base, it is how we choose to understand/print/input them that have base), as a set of choices among l1 or l2.

For example, if i is 6, that is 110 in binary, or 011 in reverse order (easier to create the test, and change nothing to the overall result), then we will choose in l1, then l2, then l2.  So

```py
i=6
[l2[k] if (2**k&i) else l1[k] for k in range(len(l1))]
```

is `[1, 'b', 'c']`.

Trick is in the test `2**k&i` which is true if kth bit of i is 1.

We just have to do that for all possible i, that is all possible set of binary choice. Since there are `len(l1)` element to choose, that is `2**len(l1)` different `i` combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

combinations = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
  for j in range(len(list2)):
    if i == j:
      combination = list1
    else:
      combination = list1[:i] + [list2[j]] + list1[i+1:]
    combinations.append(combination)

print(combinations)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Recursion

The amount of outputs we get is 2^n because we can either include a value, or its index. So, this can be done recursively:

```
def Recursive(index, value, i):
    if i < len(index):
        out = []
        prev = Recursive(index, value, i+1)
        for val in prev:
            out.append([index[i]] + val)
            out.append([value[i]] + val)
        return out
    else:
        return [[]]
```

Running your example:

```
print(Recursive([1,2,3],['a','b','c'], 0))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 2, 3], [1, 'b', 3], ['a', 'b', 3], [1, 2, 'c'], ['a', 2, 'c'], [1, 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

### Alternatively

Using binary numbers to represent whether on not we can use a number:

```
value = ['a','b','c']
result = []
for i in range(2**len(value)):
    val = str(bin(i))[2:].zfill(len(value))
    result.append([[x+1,value[x]][int(val[x])] for x in range(len(val))])
print(result)
```

Comment: You could even think of it as binary, and choose to include them based on that.